# Invalid hooks call: Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-datepicker, react-big-calendar

Hello I'm trying to use a react-big-calendar component inside a function component for my use-case. So, when I use a react-datepicker, I'm getting this hook warning. Here is my code.

```js
   

import format from "date-fns/format";
import getDay from "date-fns/getDay";
import parse from "date-fns/parse";
import startOfWeek from "date-fns/startOfWeek";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Calendar, dateFnsLocalizer } from "react-big-calendar";
import "react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css";
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
      
      
    const enloc = {
      "en-US": require("date-fns/locale/en-US"),
    };

    const localizer = dateFnsLocalizer({
      format,
      parse,
      startOfWeek,
      getDay,
      enloc,
    });
      

    function CalendarComp(props) {

      const meetings = [{
            title: "Any meet",
            start: new Date(2022, 9, 2, 7, 0, 0),
            end: new Date(2022, 9, 2, 7, 0, 0),
        }]; 

      const [newMeeting, setNewMeeting] = useState({title: "", start: new Date(), end: new Date() });
      const [allMeetings, setAllMeetings] = useState(meetings);


      const handleAdd = () => {        
          console.log("jheee")
          setAllMeetings([...allMeetings, newMeeting]); 
      }

         return (
                  <div>
                      <input type="text" value={newMeeting.title} onChange={(e) => setNewMeeting({ ...newMeeting, title: e.target.value })} />
                     <DatePicker selected={newMeeting.start} onChange={(start) => setNewMeeting({ ...newMeeting, start })} />
                      <DatePicker selected={newMeeting.end} onChange={(end) => setNewMeeting({ ...newMeeting, end })} />
                      <button onClick={handleAdd}>
                          Add
                      </button>
                  <Calendar localizer={localizer} events={allMeetings} startAccessor="start" endAccessor="end" style={{ height: 500, margin: "50px" }} />
              </div>
          );
        }

export default CalendarComp;
```

This code is giving an invalid hooks call error. When I try to comment the DatePicker lines and run, it works fine. Can you tell what I'm missing exactly. I'm using react 17.0.2 version

```
index.js:1 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

Edit: This is the code for my Route Component

```
<Switch>
      <Route exact path="/home" component={Dashboard} />
      <Route exact path="/home/calendar" component={CalendarComp} />
</Switch>
```

[image: Error Message below hooks call error]

Component Manager.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
export var ManagerReferenceNodeContext = React.createContext();
export var ManagerReferenceNodeSetterContext = React.createContext();
export function Manager(_ref) {
  var children = _ref.children;

  var _React$useState = React.useState(null),
      referenceNode = _React$useState[0],
      setReferenceNode = _React$useState[1];

  var hasUnmounted = React.useRef(false);
  React.useEffect(function () {
    return function () {
      hasUnmounted.current = true;
    };
  }, []);
  var handleSetReferenceNode = React.useCallback(function (node) {
    if (!hasUnmounted.current) {
      setReferenceNode(node);
    }
  }, []);
  return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(ManagerReferenceNodeContext.Provider, {
    value: referenceNode
  }, /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(ManagerReferenceNodeSetterContext.Provider, {
    value: handleSetReferenceNode
  }, children));
}
```

Comment: There's no invalid hooks calls in the specific code that you posted (provided you are rendering things - `<CalendarComp/>` and not just calling it `CalenderComp()`). More code is necessary.

Comment: @Adam I just updated on how I'm using the Route. Will that help?

Comment: This still all looks fine. Show more code - find the exact part of your code that is causing this hook error. Maybe it's actually coming from the component that renders the Switch? Maybe it's somewhere else? It's not in anything you've shown

Comment: @Adam The exact error shows this(added above). All other components called in similar fashion are working perfect. Can this error message deduce something?

Comment: Perhaps show the code inside your Manager component?

Comment: Manager component is not my component. Seems to be a component coming from framework. I have added the code when I checked it. @Adam

Comment: The DatePicker from 'react-datepicker' was causing the issue. Don't know why. When I imported the DatePicker from 'antd', it just worked. @Adam

Answer (score 0):

Put these 2 const values inside your CalenderComp Component function

```
const enloc = {
  "en-US": require("date-fns/locale/en-US"),
};

const localizer = dateFnsLocalizer({
  format,
  parse,
  startOfWeek,
  getDay,
  enloc,
});
```

Comment: Why would that make a difference?

Comment: @Ali Faiz That didn't help.

Comment: I believe the components may handle some states and that would cause your issue.

Comment: Your other code looks fine and there is no state that is used outside of your component. Can you share the parent component of your calendar or verify that there is not state initialization outside of any of your component?